# Issue with inserting data in azure table?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I have an issue with azure table storage. I have azure table name Html which looks like :

```
public class Html : TableServiceEntity, Ibase
{
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string File { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public byte[] CardTypeId { get; set; }
        public byte[] Card { get; set; }
        public byte[] Thumb { get; set; }
        public byte[] Tags { get; set; }
        public string ThumbUri { get; set; }
}
```

The storage was working properly. But when i am trying to store the following data, there were no exception nothing but also there were no entry of the data in the table. I have a screenShot :

[image]

In the above screenshot if you see i have placed a break-point on the code line where azure table entry is happening.The image also contain the data which was inserting in the table but when i access the entites from the table than there were no entry of this data in the table. Can anyone please tell me what i am missing here ?

Comment: can you share the implementation of AddEntity?

Comment: and share how you are retrieving the record?  Also are you setting PartitionKey & RowKey and using those values to retrive your record?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the constructor, where you need to define the Row Key and Partition Key. Can you try incorporating the same

Answer (score 0):

In the given example your are trying to insert a property with more than 64Kb (Thumb ~ 81Kb). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179338.aspx and look all table entities restrictions. You may need to store the content of this property in BLOBs instead of the TableStorage